# flashbock for opera browser (click to activate the flash)

Tags: opera, adblock

How do I make Opera replace all flash elements with a clickable button on them so that I can click on it to activate flash elements if need? This is what Flashblock plug-in for Firefox does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Flashblock for Opera**](http://my.opera.com/Lex1/blog/flashblock-for-opera-9) replaces Flash objects with a button you can click to view them.